# Programmatically Using Track Changes Comments in Outlook 2013 Add-in

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I've developed a VSTO Outlook add-in that uses the [track changes comment functionality](http://www.papercheck.com/images/2010-word-track-changes-step-8.png) of Word to highlight certain keywords in emails. This works great in Outlook 2010, but not in Outlook 2013. When I attempt to do this, I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A11FD): This command is not available.
    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Comments.Add(Range Range, Object& Text)
```

This seems to imply that the function is not available, even when using Word as the Outlook message editor. I checked this by verifying the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Mail` value `EditorPreference` is set to `0x00030001` (`196609`), which should set Word as the editor.

I know that Microsoft changed [how comments work in Office 2013](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2012/08/28/comments-and-revisions-in-word-2013.aspx), but the functionality is fundamentally the same from the user perspective.

**Does anyone have insight into why this could be happening, or more importantly a fix or workaround?**

My code is below:

```cs
var document = Inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
foreach (Word.Paragraph paragraph in document.Paragraphs) {
    range = paragraph.Range;
    range.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);
    range.MoveStart(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, highlight.Start);
    range.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, highlight.Length);
    var comment = range.Comments.Add(range, "Look at this word!");
}
```